# Using ElementTree to find a node - invalid predicate

Tags: python, xml, xpath, elementtree

I'm very new to this area so I'm sure it's just something obvious.  I'm trying to change a python script so that it finds a node in a different way but I get an "invalid predicate" error.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("/tmp/failing.xml")
doc = tree.getroot()
thingy = doc.find(".//File/Diag[@id='53']")
print(thingy.attrib)
thingy = doc.find(".//File/Diag[BaseName = 'HTTPHeaders']")
print(thingy.attrib)
```

That should find the same node twice but the second find gets the error.  Here is an extract of the XML:

```
<Diag id="53">
            <Formatted>xyz</Formatted>
            <BaseName>HTTPHeaders</BaseName>
            <Column>17</Column>
```

I hope I've not cut it down too much.  Basically, finding it with "@id" works but I want to search on that BaseName tag instead.

Actually, I want to search on a combination of tags so I have a more complicated expression lined up but I can't get the simple one to work!

Comment: I can reproduce the error with Python 2.7, but not with Python 3.7.

Comment: _"I have a more complicated expression lined up"_ - you'll probably want to use [lxml](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) instead; the [xpath support in ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support) is pretty limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the question works when using Python 3.7. If the spaces before and after the equals sign in the predicate are removed, it also works with earlier Python versions.

```
thingy = doc.find(".//File/Diag[BaseName='HTTPHeaders']")
```

See https://bugs.python.org/issue31648.

Comment: Strange, I'm using python 3.  I will have to get a cut down XML file and post a full working example - or perhaps in doing that I'll find the issue.  I will also try without the spaces just in case!  I'll get back to you.  Thanks.

Comment: But are you using Python **3.7**? The whitespace issue was fixed in that particular minor version.

Comment: Turns out I was using python 3.5 on my Linux box (3.7 when I use Windows!).  You have answered my question but I've got a follow up one.  Looking at my original script, I can see I only added the spaces to try and get rid of the original problem:  thingy = doc.find(".//File/Diag[BaseName='HTTPHeaders' and MsgNum='1063' and Line='48']") .  Even though there are no spaces, I get an error.  So I must be doing the "and" bit wrong?

Comment: PS - I'm using this as my source of info - https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_operators.asp.  Perhaps I'm reading the wrong info?

Comment: ElementTree only supports a subset of full XPath. The `and` operator does not work. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support.

Comment: Ah - OK.  Hence someone's comment about using lxml instead.  Thanks for your help.